# Problem using HTTP POST in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, http

I'm trying to send data to the webhook of an application using the code below. A connection is made but the response says "Nothing to Post". I'm new to HTTP and obviously missing something. I can retrieve data from the same webhook using http post.  Any help appreciated.

```
   NSDictionary* jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:messages forKeys:keys];
    NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"https://webhook URL .."]];
    if (fullURL) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *httpPost = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:fullURL];
        [httpPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
        [httpPost setHTTPBody:[jsonDictionary JSONData]]; // using JSONKit all seems correct
        [httpPost addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:httpPost delegate:self];
    }
```

Comment: The body you are sending is not properly encoded. It needs to be in the form of a series of name=value pairs, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP) of course for your block of JSON data you could use one pair like JSON=your json data. However you will need to take care of escaping your JSON data properly, no idea how to do that in Objective-C.

Comment: Have you checked the method [jsonDictionary JSONData] is actually returning something, and not nil instead.

Comment: As suggested, I used one JSON name=value pair in http body and after some messing about with the NSData type got it working. JSONData works well. Thanks for your comments. Very helpful.